# Using roles only in certain endpoints | Spring Boot Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

context: I added a role admin to certain endpoints, and now, I need the role client, to call the other endpoints that don't require the admin role.

my question is : is it possible to call the endpoints that dont need the admin role with no role ?

is my question clear ? thanks in advance !

Comment: You can this validation with spring AOP.

Comment: Share your code so we can have an idea of your use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could let some endpoints to require no authorization/authentication like this

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/endpoint1","/endpoint2").permitAll();
    }
```

in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class.

Comment: thats nice, but i have a ton of other endpoints, do i need to write them all ?

Comment: You can group many of them together under the same directory like this antMatchers("/endpoint1/*").permitAll();